# Create references to rust strings in two separate vectors

Tags: rust

I have a vector of input `String`s and I'd like to create two vectors containing references, `&str`, to those strings.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying (the input is replaced with a simple vector initialisation):

```
let colours = vec!["red".to_string(), "black".to_string(), "blue".to_string()];
let mut starts_with_b = Vec::new();
let mut ends_with_e = Vec::new();

for colour in colours {
    if colour.starts_with("b") {
        starts_with_b.push(&*colour);
    }
    if colour.ends_with("e") {
        ends_with_e.push(&*colour);
    }
}

println!("{:?}", starts_with_b);
println!("{:?}", ends_with_e);
```

This code produces the compiler error "'colour' does not live long enough".  How can I resolve this problem?

I've seen that this problem does not exist if I start off with string references, `&str`:

```
let colours = vec!["red", "black", "blue"];
let mut starts_with_b = Vec::new();
let mut ends_with_e = Vec::new();

for colour in colours {
    if colour.starts_with("b") {
        starts_with_b.push(colour);
    }
    if colour.ends_with("e") {
        ends_with_e.push(colour);
    }
}

println!("{:?}", starts_with_b);
println!("{:?}", ends_with_e);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` loop on the reference of `colours`:

```
let colours = vec!["red".to_string(), "black".to_string(), "blue".to_string()];
let mut starts_with_b = Vec::new();
let mut ends_with_e = Vec::new();

for colour in &colours {
    if colour.starts_with("b") {
        starts_with_b.push(colour);
    }
    if colour.ends_with("e") {
        ends_with_e.push(colour);
    }
}

println!("{:?}", starts_with_b);
println!("{:?}", ends_with_e);
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your code comes from the fact the temporary `colour` variable is a *moved* `String`, which means it's very short-lived. In your `starts_with_b` and `ends_with_e` vectors you need to store references to the values in `colours`, which can easily be done by simply *not* moving the values in `colours` while iterating them. The easiest way to do that is by doing this:

```
for colour in &colours {
```

instead of this:

```
for colour in colours {
```

That way `colour` will be of type `&String`, instead of a (moved) `String`, so you can simply push `colour` directly.

Note that that way the types of `starts_with_b` and `ends_with_e` will be `Vec<&String>` and not `Vec<&str>`, as you asked for. I presume that won't be an issue for you, but if it is, you can easily make them  `Vec<&str>` by simply calling `push(&colour[..])` instead of `push(colour)`.